# Extract data with sed command which matches time range and pattern

Tags: linux, logging, sed, grep

I want to extract lines from a large log file(about 10GB) and copy data into a separate file.
The output should match with the given time range and the given text.

I tried the below command which only match with the time range , but the whole content is copying to the file without filtering. (Then I thought to grep the given text form mycopy file.)

```
sed '/2020-07-21 17:28:00/,/2020-07-21 17:44:00/w mycopy' myLogFile  > mycopy
```

Its better if I can include the text to be matched at the same time but I don't understand how to do that.
I want something similar to this.

```
sed '/givenTextTobeMatched/2020-07-21 17:28:00/,/2020-07-21 17:44:00/' myLogFile > mycopy
```

Your response on that is really appreciating.

Comment: Can you please add sample input and expected output.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks a lot, the command you provided worked for me. That was exactly what I needed. If you can provide it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I removed the comments and posted an answer instead, slightly expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex to identify a time range will only work if the start and end times both occur in the log file. If nothing was logged at 17:44:00 then `sed` will copy the entire rest of the file because the end condition is never met. Probably switch to a higher-level language like Awk if you can't guarantee that there are log events for every second.

Syntactically

```
sed '/2020-07-21 17:28:00/,/2020-07-21 17:44:00/!d;/givenTextTobeMatched/!d' myLogFile
```

would do what you are asking. Notice the negations; first,  we delete the lines outside the range, than the ones which *don't* match the pattern. (In some sense

```
sed -n '/2020-07-21 17:28:00/,/2020-07-21 17:44:00/{
    /givenTextTobeMatched/p
}' myLogFile
```

might be more idiomatic and logical, but it's harder to portably squeeze onto one line.)